# Getting time intervals in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, rails-activerecord

I have an external service that allows me to log users into my website.

To avoid getting kicked out of it for overuse I use a `MySQL` table on the following form that caches user accesses:

```
username (STRING) | last access (TIMESTAMP) | has access? (TINYINT(1) - BOOLEAN)
```

If the user had access on a given time I trust he has access and don't query the service during a day, that is

```
query_again = !user["last access"].between?(Time.now, 1.day.ago)
```

This always returns true for some reason, any help with this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ranges (which you effectively use here), it is generally expected that the lower number is the start and the higher number is the end. Thus, it should work for you if you just switch the condition in your `between?` call

```
query_again = !user["last access"].between?(1.day.ago, Time.now)
```

You can test this yourself easily in IRB:

```
1.hour.ago.between?(Time.now, 1.day.ago)
# => false

1.hour.ago.between?(1.day.ago, Time.now)
# => true
```